# How do I use reflect to check if the type of a struct field is interface{}?

Tags: go, reflection

I am using the reflect package to determine the type of a struct field is `interface{}`

I want to do the comparison like so (where `t` is a `reflect.Type`):

```
if  t == reflect.TypeOf(interface{}) {

}
```

The problem is that the compiler complains: `type interface {} is not an expression`.

Is there anyway to check if the type of a struct field is an `interface{}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`interface{}` is a type, and [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) expects a value. So you can't pass the literal `interface{}` to it. You can only pass a value.

Back to the original question. Let's see a `struct` example:

```
type My struct {
    A int
    B interface{}
    C io.Reader
}
```

You want to tell if the type of a field is `interface{}`. Acquire the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) of the `struct` type, then you can access the fields using `Type.Field()` or `Type.FieldByName()`.

This gives you a value of type [`reflect.StructField`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField) which stores the type of the field.

So far so good. But what should we compare it to? `interface{}` is an interface type with 0 methods. You can't have (instantiate) a value of that type. You can only have values of concrete types, but yes, they may be wrapped in an interface type.

You could use `Type.Kind`, and compare it to `reflect.Interface`, which tells you if it's an interface, but this is `true` for all interface types. You could also check if it has 0 methods with `Type.NumMethod()`, which must be 0 for `interface{}`, but other interfaces could also have 0 methods...

You may use `Type.Name`, but since `interface{}` is a *unnamed* type, its name is the empty string `""` (and there are other unnamed types). You may use `Type.String()` which returns `"interface {}"` for the empty interface:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(My{})

for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    f := t.Field(i)
    fmt.Printf("Field %q, type: %-12v, type name: %-8q, is interface{}: %v\n",
        f.Name, f.Type,
        f.Type.Name(),
        f.Type.String() == "interface {}",
    )
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gN2Itm17T9)):

```
Field "A", type: int         , type name: "int"   , is interface{}: false
Field "B", type: interface {}, type name: ""      , is interface{}: true
Field "C", type: io.Reader   , type name: "Reader", is interface{}: false
```

You might find this related question interesting / useful: [Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523)

Answer (score 7):

You can get the type of the interface `Y` by creating a nil instance and using reflection:

```
yType := reflect.TypeOf((*Y)(nil)).Elem()
```

and then use the expression

```
reflect.TypeOf(x).Implements(yType)
```

to check if the type implements the interface.

Interfaces themselves can not be instantiated. The interface{} interface which is the empty interface is implemented by all types so all fields implement that.

https://play.golang.org/p/gRfheIW_9Y

Actually it also works with the empty interface{} itself but this will always return true (if i'm not missing something):

https://play.golang.org/p/29rWP4LtIo

Comment: What if Y is an `interface{}`, i got error: `cannot call non-function Y (type interface {})`