# How to use Go reflection pkg to get the type of a slice struct field?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, types, slice

I'm trying to use reflection to build a routine that will list the Name, Kind and Type of all fields in an arbitrary struct that gets passed in. Here is what I've got so far:

```
type StatusVal int
type Foo struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
type Bar struct {
    Status StatusVal
    FSlice []Foo
}

func ListFields(a interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
        f := v.Field(j)
        n := v.Type().Field(j).Name
        t := f.Type().Name()
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s  Kind: %s  Type: %s\n", n, f.Kind(), t)
    }
}

func main() {
    var x Bar
    ListFields(&x)
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Name: Status  Kind: int  Type: StatusVal
Name: FSlice  Kind: slice  Type:
```

When the field is a slice, the type is blank. I tried several ways to get the slice's data type, but all attempts resulted in a panic... usually this one:

```
reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on slice Value
```

What changes need to be made to this code so that the type for all fields, including slices, will be listed in the output?

Here's the playground link:  https://play.golang.org/p/zpfrYkwvlZ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A slice type given in a *type literal* like `[]Foo` is an *unnamed* type, hence `Type.Name()` returns an empty string `""`.

Use `Type.String()` instead:

```
t := f.Type().String()
```

And then the output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PLuIFjdvez)):

```
Name: Status  Kind: int  Type: main.StatusVal
Name: FSlice  Kind: slice  Type: []main.Foo
```

See related question to know more about types and their names: [Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523)