# find underlying type of custom type in golang

Tags: go, typeof

```
type M map[string]interface{}
var item M
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(item))
```

returns `main.M`.

How can I find underlying type of item as `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: What is the root type? I've never heard such term.

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can fetch the precise structure of the type, if that's what you mean with "root type":

```
var item M
t := reflect.TypeOf(item)
fmt.Println(t.Kind()) // map
fmt.Println(t.Key())  // string
fmt.Println(t.Elem()) // interface {}
```

[test it](https://play.golang.org/p/BEfWYyJ4Ne)

From there you're free to display it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box way, but you can construct the underlying type by hand:

```
type M map[string]interface{}
...
var m M
t := reflect.TypeOf(m)
if t.Kind() == reflect.Map {
    mapT := reflect.MapOf(t.Key(), t.Elem())
    fmt.Println(mapT)
}
```