# Is there a way to order types quickly in Go?

Tags: go, types

I have a package which has to order Go types, *quickly*.

Currently I use `reflect.Type`s, get their name with `Name()`, and order the names as strings:

```
if type1.Name() < type2.Name() { ...
```

However, it uses a string comparison. It works, but I am looking for a more quick solution.

*How* exactly this comparison works, is not an important thing to me - only what I need,

1. the result of the comparison should be same in the life of process.
2. it should be non-equal for different types, but equal for the same type.

Comparing the `reflect.Type` variables directly with `<` doesn't work, as this operation is not defined for `reflect.Type`s in Go.

It would be possible to generate a hash of the type names to 64- or 128 bit integers, and then compare these integers. It is a possibility, however I am looking for a yet quicker solution.

Another possibility would be to compare the `reflect.Type` variables by their unsafe pointers (casted to `int64`), but as far I know, there is no guarantee in Go that the *unsafe* pointer addresses won't change in the life cycle of the process. Thus, I would lose my (1) requirement.

Comment: Also the *negative* answers are useful and acceptable. *"There is no standard way to do that"* is exactly an useful answer, like *"You can do this with..."* - I will know, I can stop the search.

Comment: Do you control all the types in question or do you want this to work for built in types and any other type?

Comment: The reason of the downvote, and the close vote as "go to the SU" are unclear to me, but I am open for any advices.

Comment: @KennyGrant Ideally, for both of them. I don't control all the types - it will be in a package. It will be called by mainly for not builtin types.

Comment: You could use a `Register(name string, v interface{})` function, similar to that of the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Register) or [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RegisterFormat) packages and hash the names provided.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Thanks. I checked these functions, but as far as I can see it, they don't compare types. How do these functions compare Types?

Comment: I'm saying you'd need to write your own Register function and store hashes of the registered type names, so you could compare them yourself.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Thanks again. It is the option I described in the before the last paragraph of the post. I think, it is a strong indication, that there is no quicker solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `Type.Name()` is bad

Using `Type.Name()` for comparison is a really bad idea as there are many anonymous types where `Type.Name()` returns the empty string such as `[]int`, `*int` etc. Also the name returned by `Type.Name()` does not include the package name, so for example names of `time.Time` and `foo.Time` will be `"Time"` and therefore considered equal. No more is needed to be said. Check out [Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523) for more details.

#### With an internal registry

An easy and fast way would be to assign a single integer (e.g. an `int` value) to all types that need to be compared, and then you don't need any `string` comparison nor hashing, just compare the assigned `int` values.

Only question left is how to assign and *remember* these `int` values. The assigned values may simply be continuous values, starting with 1, then 2, 3 etc. This assignment and lookup may be automatic (hidden from our eyes).

Essentially we want a function something like this:

```
// Compare compares 2 types, returns a negative number
// if t1 < t2, a positive number if t1 > t2, and 0 otherwise.
func Compare(t1, t2 reflect.Type) int {
}
```

And the implementation is very simple / compact:

```
var (
    registry = map[reflect.Type]int{}
    max      int
)

func value(t reflect.Type) int {
    v := registry[t]
    if v == 0 {
        max++
        v, registry[t] = max, max
    }
    return v
}

// Compare compares 2 types, returns a negative number
// if t1 < t2, a positive number if t1 > t2, and 0 otherwise.
func Compare(t1, t2 reflect.Type) int {
    v1, v2 := value(t1), value(t2)
    return v1 - v2
}
```

Testing it:

```
tstring := reflect.TypeOf("")
tint := reflect.TypeOf(int(1))
ttime := reflect.TypeOf(time.Time{})

fmt.Println(Compare(tstring, tstring)) // 0
fmt.Println(Compare(tint, ttime))      // -1, tint gets registered first
fmt.Println(Compare(ttime, tint))      // 1
fmt.Println(Compare(tint, tint))       // 0
fmt.Println(Compare(tstring, ttime))   // -2
fmt.Println(Compare(ttime, tstring))   // 2
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wD2tppiKYs)):

```
0
-1
1
0
-2
2
```

#### Making it safe for concurrent use

One weakness though: the implementation is not safe for concurrent use (by multiple goroutines). If we need safety for concurrent use, access to the `registry` map (and to the `max` variable) must be synchronized:

```
var mu sync.RWMutex

func value(t reflect.Type) int {
    mu.RLock()
    v := registry[t]
    mu.RUnlock()
    if v == 0 {
        mu.Lock()
        max++
        v, registry[t] = max, max
        mu.Unlock()
    }
    return v
}
```

The rest is unchanged. The output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Oo-YBTwBgl).

#### Under the hood (looking closer)

Now this `Compare()` implies using a lock under the hood. Also in order to get the assigned integer value of a type, we have to index a map. The type of the key in this map is `reflect.Type` which is an interface type. Current implementation of `reflect.Type` is `*reflect.rtype` which is a pointer, so it is still fast enough as only a pointer is hashed and then looked for in a bucket (the builtin map is a hashmap implementation).

#### The fastest solution (getting rid of locks and map indexing)

Now this `Compare()` implies using a lock under the hood (and indexing a map), so that may still be an unacceptable "burden" if you really seek the fastest solution. You can easily get rid of using those all the time when comparison is needed if you acquire the internal `int` value assigned for the type, and use that, even directly to compare to another type's value.

For this, all you need to do is "publish" (export) the `value()` function:

```
func Value(t reflect.Type) int {
    // ...
}
```

And `Compare()` may even be removed. So libraries that need this kind of type comparison can query the integer value assigned to a type, and they can "cache" this value to avoid having to call it again (as it won't change during the lifetime of a process), and it can be compared to other values obtained by this `Value()` function.

For example:

```
vstring := Value(reflect.TypeOf(""))
vint := Value(reflect.TypeOf(int(1)))
vtime := Value(reflect.TypeOf(time.Time{}))

fmt.Println(vstring - vstring) // 0
fmt.Println(vint - vtime)      // -1, tint gets registered first
fmt.Println(vtime - vint)      // 1
fmt.Println(vint - vint)       // 0
fmt.Println(vstring - vtime)   // -2
fmt.Println(vtime - vstring)   // 2
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iFFr4kPDYI).