# Is it possible using reflection in golang to get the underlying type of a user defined type?

Tags: go

I have this type:

```
type T string
```

Can I get the underlying type of an object of `T`? For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type T string

func main() {
    var t = T("what")
    tt := reflect.TypeOf(t)
    fmt.Println(tt) // prints T, i need string
}
```

Comment: See related: [Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect/37292523#37292523).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly "the underlying type", but for your case, you don't want that, you want its [`Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind), from [`Type.Kind()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type):

```
var t = T("what")
k := reflect.TypeOf(t).Kind()
fmt.Println(k)
```

Playable example: https://play.golang.org/p/M75wsTwUHkv

Note that Kind *is not* synonymous with "underlying type", which isn't really a thing, as you can see here: https://play.golang.org/p/900YGm2BnPV

Comment: if `t` is of type `*T` can I still get to the "underlying type"? i.e. `string` and not `ptr`

Comment: Yes. See [`Type.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type). https://play.golang.org/p/c64GDPglcwh

Answer (score 4):

You can call [Type.Kind()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) , which will return you one of [these constants](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind)

```
fmt.Println(tt.Kind()) // prints string
```

If you don't know if it's a pointer or not, you need an extra check and call [Type.Elem()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem)

```
var kind reflect.Kind 
if tt.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    kind = tt.Elem().Kind()
} else {
    kind = tt.Kind()
}
fmt.Println(kind)
```